# Spring MVC Ajax Request not active in controller class

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am new at spring MVC .I am trying to do ajax request on spring MVC. This seem when ajax call act controller method doesnt response.But I didnt understand why it is.
But I am getting this error on browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of http://localhost:8080/spapp/ajaxtest.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Here My method in controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ajaxtest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String ajaxtest() {
    String result = "This is Ajax text from ajaxTest Method";
    return result;
}
```

Here My Ajax call in index.jsp:

```
$(function(){

            $(document).on("click","button#save",function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"ajaxtest.html",
                    data:{test:"test"},
                    success:function(response){
                        $("div#response").html(response);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
```

What can I do fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with `url:"ajaxtest"` you don't have to put `.html` at the end because you have declared your endpoint `value = "/ajaxtest"`.

Comment: This is not helped me :(

Comment: Then you have another issue.

Comment: I d'ont know, I think the problem is in the controller Class or Java configuration. Try with the full url : `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ajaxtest` (change  the port with yours).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.I removed `type="POST"` in ajax call.after it runs.

Comment: This would suggest that the controller code you included in the question is not what you're actually running.

Comment: After removing `type="POST"` jQuery would use GET by default and your controller is annotated to respond to POST only. There's no way this change alone would "fix" your code.